# create venn diagram using existing counts in R?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I was wondering if I can generate a Venn diagram using `vennDiagram` in R without generating the counts matrix using `vennCounts` but having a similar matrix saved. So let's say I have this matrix:

```
G S P Counts

1 1 1 117898    
1 1 0 125901    
1 0 1 119360    
0 1 1 118086    
1 0 0 3505      
0 1 0 753       
0 0 1 701       
0 0 0 0
```

and I call it M. when I do

```
m <- as.matrix(M)
vennDiagram(m)
```

I see:

> Error in vennDiagram(m) : Can't plot Venn diagram for more than 3 sets

Is there any way around this problem? I am trying to bypass generating the matrix of 1 and 0s as I already have the counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hacky way to do it. I generate artificial sets that contain fake members composed of integers. But it works

```
require(VennDiagram)
lines = "1 1 1 117898    
1 1 0 125901    
1 0 1 119360    
0 1 1 118086    
1 0 0 3505      
0 1 0 753       
0 0 1 701       
0 0 0 0"
con <- textConnection(lines)
data <- read.table(con)
names(data) = c('G','S','P')

close(con)

sets = vector(mode = 'list', length = ncol(data)-1)
names(sets) = names(data)[1:(ncol(data)-1)]
lastElement = 0
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    elements = lastElement:(lastElement+data[i,ncol(data)]-1)
    lastElement = elements[length(elements)]+1
    for (j in 1:(ncol(data)-1)){
        if (data[i,j]==1){
            sets[[j]]=c(sets[[j]],elements)
        }
    }
}
laVenn = venn.diagram(sets,filename=NULL)
plot.new()
grid.draw(laVenn)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I thought you wanted to avoid creating the fake object. samira's answer is probably a better way to it since this can fail if your total object count is very high (around 2*10^9) and uses unnecessary ram.

Comment: you are right but your solution was faster than what ever object creation I tried myself and that was the main burden although with the one mentioned below no matrix creation on any type is needed! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I figured one can also use this solution if teh individual numbers and shared areas are avaiable draw.triple.venn(area1, area2, area3, n12, n23, n13, n123) where area is teh toatal size and nxy is the shared area between areax and areay. 
so 
draw.triple.venn(130868, 126842, 120249, 125901, 118086, 119360, 117898), I'd send the Venn diagram image but i need more reputation to do so!